# SQL Server create table, possibility to skip rows with constraint violation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

currently I am using Import/Export assistent to import Excel tables into SQL Server, now I want to add constraints in the import SQL Command, but my data contains rows that violate those constraints... is it somehow possible to just skip those rows but add all the other correct rows? I get an error message, and import aborts.. 
or what is the best way to do this? I added constraint after importing, but only could do so in the GUI for constraints, and not as CLI command, because it was also violated immediately because my dataset contained those invalid rows already..?! 
how is one doing this? I want either skip those lines on import, or get a warning with the rowID, or just abort import on those lines that violate the constraints in the future when I add new data...

Comment: What kind of constraints? Like primary key constraints?

Comment: nope, I mean constraints on table columns, like ranges [columnX BETWEEN 0 and 1]...or some other functions... if column == value... etc.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this would be to import the Excel tables into new tables on SQL Server that have no constraints.   Then from there, use a SQL INSERT..SELECT query to Select only rows that won't violate your constraints, and insert them into the final destination table.

Comment: omg, is this really made so stupid and complicated in SQL Server? they just could have used a user prompt where they would be asked what to do.. to skip the rows or whatever or select a field for that... thats typical for Microsoft -.-

Comment: Well the import/export wizard builds an SSIS package and executes it behind the scenes.  If you were to build a package manually, you could build this logic into it yourself, but as far as I know, there is no simple "switch" built into the wizard that will cause it to use this logic.